# How to use <form:form> </form:form> TAG using HTML in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How do use the

> `<form:form> </form:form>`

tag using HTML in Spring MVC applications?

I am not using .jsp. Instead **I am using HTML pages**.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use it in an HTML page...

To use the `<form:form>` tag in JSP, you must use a JSP taglib:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

This taglib allows to use the Spring `form` feature. Example:

```
<form:form
    method="POST"
    action="/spring-mvc-xml/addEmployee" modelAttribute="employee">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="id">Id</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="id"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="contactNumber">
              Contact Number</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="contactNumber"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

To use this form you need to send an Employee class object as ***ModelAttribute*** from your controller...

One major remainder is all ***path*** attributes in the form elements should be the same as the Employee class  property name...

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private long id;
    private String contactNumber;

    // Standard getters and setters
}
```

For more help, we can see this link [reference of my post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial).

Answer (score 2):

this is my answer

```
<form:form
   
    action="/action" modelAttribute="student">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="email">email</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>  
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

import above tag

and in controller

@RequestMapping("/test")

```
public String index1(Model model)
{
    
    //  String name1=name;
        model.addAttribute("student",new Studentdata());
    return "form.jsp";
}
```

in action URL

@RequestMapping("/action")

```
    public String jasper1(@ModelAttribute("student") Studentdata student)
    {
        
    System.out.print("name"+student.getName());
    System.out.print("name"+student.getEmail());
    
    return"action.jsp";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not a specific `<form:form> </form:form>` in HTML, but you can use it like this:

```
<form action="../store" method="post" >
    // Your code
</form>
```